# Any advice on parsing an OPML file with PHP so I can import the addresses into a mySql database?

Tags: php, mysql, import, opml

I want to be able to have the user select an OPML file that contains a large number of bookmarks, then loop through each one and toss it in a mysql database.

Any direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In the end, parsing any file comes down to a few things:

- Get the file from `$_FILES`
  [Handling File Uploads (Documentation)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)
- Load the file into a reader
   [SimpleXML (Documenation)](https://www.php.net/simplexml)
- Check that it is in the right format
  (This will most likely just be checking that SimpleXML didn't throw an error)
- Loop through the data
- Sanitize any data going into the database
- Enter it into the database

If this is a big file, you will also want to look it things like `max_upload_size` and other upload size restrictions. Also, look into a way to let the user know you are working if the script takes a while to process the file.